# How to send date value as POST parameter?

Tags: http, date, post, parameters

What is the best way to send a date value (eg. `10/08/12`) as a HTTP `POST` parameter?

Can forward slashes be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL encoding function should be used in the client software.

eg. in .NET it is `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

Answer (score 2):

best without slashes . I recommend sending the value using this format :

```
20120810
```

Fixed length